# Sql Server Optimize left Join

Tags: sql-server, performance, join, query-performance

Hello i've these 2 tables :

```
Table Contac_Group
ID       int
Grp_ID   int
Grp_Name nvarchar(80)
Is_Grp_Hidden  Bit

Table Contacts 
ID     int
Contact_Grp_ID  int /* this values is from Contact_Group Grp_ID */
Contact_Name nvarchar(80)
Contact_Email nvarchar(15)
```

and this's the Join query i use :

```
SELECT 
       a.Contact_Grp_ID
      ,a.Contact_Name
      FROM (
    SELECT 
          Contact_Grp_ID
          ,Contact_Name
    FROM Cnts.dbo.[Contacts]
    GROUP BY Contact_Grp_ID,Contact_Name
) a
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
           Grp_ID
          ,Grp_Name
          ,Is_Grp_Hidden
    FROM Cnts.dbo.[Contac_Group]
    where Is_Grp_Hidden =0
    GROUP BY Grp_ID,Grp_Name,Is_Grp_Hidden

) b ON a.Contact_Grp_ID = b.Grp_ID;
```

So in case i've million of Contacts Data how this inner join can be optimized ?

thank you

Comment: Easy optimization A: remove the `LEFT JOIN` and subquery `b` completely.

Comment: @ ypercubeᵀᴹ , can you please explain me this approach?

Comment: What indexes do the tables have? How many rows are returned by both queries? Why are you using `GROUP BY` with no aggregation? Why are you left joining onto the derived table and selecting no columns from it?

Comment: Why the title says INNER join but the code has LEFT join?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This query doesn't make much sense to me...

First: Why do you have a table with two IDs ?

```
Table Contact_Group
ID       int
Grp_ID   int
Grp_Name nvarchar(80)
Is_Grp_Hidden  Bit
```

I assume that the group is uniquely identified by Grp_ID => get then rid of ID. If this is not the case, and you *can* have repeated Grp_ID, then *What does this mean?*, *Which is the use case that needs this?*

Second: Why do you need to have subqueries like the following one?

```
SELECT 
       Grp_ID
      ,Grp_Name
      ,Is_Grp_Hidden
FROM Contact_Group
where Is_Grp_Hidden =0
GROUP BY Grp_ID,Grp_Name,Is_Grp_Hidden
```

Optimizations:

1. You `LEFT JOIN` with a subquery (`b`) and you do not use ANY column from `b` => just don't `LEFT JOIN`, it accomplishes nothing. [It would be different if this were an `INNER JOIN` instead of a `LEFT JOIN`].

   You're now having just this query (equivalent to the original one, yet simpler:

   ```
   SELECT 
        a.Contact_Grp_ID
       ,a.Contact_Name
   FROM 
       (
       SELECT 
            Contact_Grp_ID
           ,Contact_Name
       FROM 
           Contacts
       GROUP BY 
           Contact_Grp_ID, Contact_Name
       ) a ;
   ```
2. Your subquery (`a`) and the outer one retrieve the same columns, without any intermediate computed column or the like: you can push them up, and just have:

   ```
   SELECT 
        Contact_Grp_ID
       ,Contact_Name
   FROM 
       Contacts
   GROUP BY 
       Contact_Grp_ID, Contact_Name ;
   ```

And that's all.

(NOTE: I don't understand the meaning of this setup; these are purely formal transformations giving equivalent results.)

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_next&fiddle=c2d7566e8e2e24bfab30d60615ab3f44)*

Comment: so many thanks for your replay , but in future i'll fetch the `Grp_Name` and some other values from the `Contac_Group` table that's why i tried to Left Join , so please correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: Then change your question... You don't need to optimize this query, you need to optimize **another one**.

Comment: @ joanolo  which one please ?

Comment: The one "**in future** i'll fetch the Grp_Name and some other values"

Comment: @ joanolo what about the `Bit` value of the `Is_Grp_Hidden` in `Contac_Group` , when this value is `True` the Contact will be hidden too

Comment: @randydom: The point is, the query in your question doesn't pull any columns from `b`. Since it's doing a left join (which is an outer join) on `b` and isn't selecting *anything* from `b`, the `b` side of the query is simply redundant. If it was an inner join, it would at least filter the `a` rows. As it is, it's doing nothing, so it's not needed. If and when you need to pull columns from `b`, then it will be a different query and a different question.

Comment: @Andriy M  so many thanks for this explanation , can you just help me to correct the Query so that i'll reflect the Question , again thank you .